# Why does printing a variable in Go cause a stack overflow?

Tags: go

The most generalized version of the error that I could find looks like this:

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    values := []any{1,2,3}
    values = append(values[:1],values[1:])
    fmt.Println(values)
}
```

Which causes a stack overflow (funny I'm posting on this site). If I remove `values` from the print statement and replace it with something else (such as `0`), it doesn't throw an error and it prints properly.

If I use `...` to use the append variadically, the code runs properly and prints `[1 2 3]`.

I also tried putting `fmt.Println("This section of code reached successfully!")` between the change to `values` and the other print statement, but that prints before the error, which means that `fmt.Println(values)` is the line causing the overflow.

I can print the first item of `values` on its own without error, but printing the second item of the list on its own causes the overflow.

This version of the code runs without error:

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    values := append([]any{1},[]any{2,3})
    fmt.Println(values)
}
```

Why does this happen? This is a far more generalized version of an error I'm experiencing in one of my projects.

Comment: You need to explode the second slice when calling `append`: `append(values[:1],values[1:]...)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen As I stated, I tried appending like that. I know it works. I don't want to append the contents of the list, I want to append the list. The result should be `[1 [2 3]]`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Slices are not arrays, they are views into arrays. Here is a simplified example, for illustration:

```
values := []any{1, 2, 3}
slice := values[1:]       // [2, 3]
values[1] = 100
fmt.Println(slice)        // [100, 3]
```

If you change an element of an array, the slice into it changes as well, and vice versa.

Now, when you append a slice of an array to that same array, you get into self-referential stuff.

```
values := []any{1,2,3}
values = append(values[:1],values[1:])  // [1, values[1:]]
```

`values[1:]` is `[values[1:]]` (because it is a live view into `values`, not `[2, 3]` as you assumed), which is `[[values[1:]]]`... so `values` is not `[1, 2, 3]`, but `[1, [[[[[[[[[[[[stackoverflow`

Note that the structure itself is fine, though not what you want. It is only an error when you try to print it, since `fmt.Println` doesn't know how to handle a recursive structure.

In order to do what you want, you need to first copy the slice before you append it, so you don't end up adding to `values` a recursive reference into `values`.

Comment: How do I copy the slice?

Comment: [slices.Clone](https://pkg.go.dev/slices#Clone) if you are on latest Go version (I think it was added with 1.22). Otherwise create a new one with the same size and use `copy` to copy all elements from the old slice to the new.

Comment: First allocate a new array for the elements to go into: `slicedValues := make([]any, len(values))` and then copy the elements over: `copy(slicedValues, values[1:])` (if you can't `Clone`)

Comment: @Flummox, please start with [this](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) and [this](https://go.dev/blog/slices) — they should make you covered on arrays and slices.

Comment: Not important though, please fix `  // [9, 3]` into `   // [100, 3]`

Answer (score 4):

Your append statement is placing the original `values` slice within itself, creating a recursive data structure. The only way to ensure this can't happen is to create a new slice and copy the values in.

```
values := []any{1, 2, 3}
values = append(values[:1], slices.Clone(values[1:]))
fmt.Println(values)
```

results in `[1 [2 3]]`

Answer (score 2):

If you always need the first element and then the rest in the sub-slice, then this is more efficient. It doesn't copy the slice, but creates a new one and fills it with the existing slice.

```golang
values := []any{1, 2, 3}
values = append([]any{}, values[0], values[1:])
fmt.Println(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method append() is causing the slice to become recursively nested.

```
values := []any{1,2,3}
values = append(values[:1], values[1:])
fmt.Println(values)
```

Here, when you use append() with values[1:], you're attempting to append a slice to values[:1], which results in a nested slice structure. This recursion of nested slices eventually leads to a stack overflow when you try to print values.

One solution is to copy the slice before you append:

```
values := []any{1, 2, 3}
sliceCopy := make([]any, len(values)-1)
copy(sliceCopy, values[1:])
values = append(values[:1], sliceCopy)
fmt.Println(values)
```